# Implementing Domain Driven Design Book Confusion

Tags: transactions, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

I am currently reading "Implementing Domain Driven Design" book and on one of the pages shows

```
public class ProductBacklogItemService ... {
    ...
    @Transactional
    public void planProductBacklogItem(
        String aTenantId, String aProductId,
        String aSummary, String aCategory,
        String aBacklogItemType, String aStoryPoints) {

        Product product =
            productRepository.productOfId(
                    new TenantId(aTenantId),
                    new ProductId(aProductId));

        BacklogItem plannedBacklogItem =
            product.planBacklogItem(
                    aSummary,
                    aCategory,
                    BacklogItemType.valueOf(aBacklogItemType),
                    StoryPoints.valueOf(aStoryPoints));

        backlogItemRepository.add(plannedBacklogItem);
    }
    ...
}
```

His book also says Reference: In DDD the Aggregate should represent the transactional boundary. A transaction that requires the involvement of more than one aggregate is often a sign that either the model should be refined, or the transactional requirements should be reviewed, or both.

In the above example, wouldn't Product and BacklogItem be 2 different aggregates in a single transaction?  I am confused.  Can anyone share some thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that 'the involvement of' in this case may mean 'changes to' and since `Product` is not modified only one AR is affected.  I actually read this bit last night and just a bit further on he does mention that one should really aim to only manipulate one AR per transaction.  So it seems as though there will be exceptions.

It isn't a bad idea to only manipulate a single AR per transaction and typically you'll find that you end up with such a design anyway.

There are always going to be exceptions to the rule but those should be carefully considered.

Comment: I think product contains a collection of backlogitem, hence two ARs are affected, both Product and BacklogItem.

Comment: Still, this is not a dogma but a guideline. When you create an aggregate, it's common to do it by another aggregate. http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is where the initial 'large' AR was split into different ARs.  So initially the `Product` contained the collections but they should no longer be on `Product` as a repository represents that collection now.  The `Product` now only contains factory methods, probably to create the association properly.  Here is a post by Udi Dahan along the same lines: http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/